# Multiply a number by 3.5 without using *, /, % operators

Tags: java, math

How would you multiply a number by 3.5 without using `*`, `/` or `%`, operators?

The number may be signed or unsigned.

Comment: Smells like a homework problem... how do you think it can be done?

Comment: In the case this it's not homework, why you would like to do it?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I hope you know that multiplication of `x` with `n` means addition of `x` `n` no. of times.

Comment: Try using the `+` and shift `>>` operators. What have you tried so far that's not working?

Comment: I take a input from user and add it three times and add half of number by >> operator but it act only for even number not for odd number

Comment: You could always add it to itself `3` times and then add anothe `1/2` of it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code golf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

number of times to add=n
double sum=0;

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
sum=sum+3.5;
}
```

Comment: LOL I didn't notice we can use `+`.

Comment: same here,,i thought all arithmetic operators are not allowed

Comment: yes ..very simple one

Comment: -1 You missed the part where it says: *"The number may be signed or unsigned."* You also read a restriction into the question that isn't there: The number need not be of integral type.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.log(Math.pow(Math.exp(x), 3.5))`